# How to reload line profiler sources in Ipython

Tags: python, debugging, profiling, ipython

I want to run the line profiler on a module, but even when I reload the module itself
and run `%reload_ext line_profiler`, the source text does not get refreshed -- the line numbers are still correct, but the text shown refers to outdated text. Only closing iPython and loading the line profiler and module again makes the text refresh.

How do I make the source text refresh without reloading ipython?

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to restart the kernel from the menu bar in [iPython](https://ipython.org)/[Jupyter](http://jupyter.org), under the Kernel button, without leaving the GUI.